# Has The IE8 XSS Filter XSS Flaw Been Fixed?

Tags: xss

You may remember: X-XSS-Protection: 0

http://hackademix.net/2009/11/21/ies-xss-filter-creates-xss-vulnerabilities/

Has this been fixed in IE8? IE9? IE10? Is it implemented in IE7?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The XSS Filter is implemented in IE8 and above.  The issue was addressed in IE8 in [MS10-002](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/bulletin/MS10-002), prior to the release of IE9 & IE10.

Comment: Funny thing - I wanted to forward this question to you, but you found it anyway ;)